# c++ trying to find max value for each row in array

Tags: c++, arrays, max

I don't understand why it is not finding the max for each row
here is what it prints out:
Enter the scores of the 1st competition: 7.5 9.3 8.5 7.2 10.0

Enter the scores of the 2nd competition: 8.1 7.8 9.2 10.0 7.7

Enter the scores of the 3rd competition: 8.5 6.7 8.7 9.4 8.2

Enter the scores of the 4th competition: 7.4 9.3 9.6 8.9 9.1

Enter the scores of the 5th competition: 8.5 7.7 9.7 8.3 8.4

the winner of competition #1 10

the winner of competition #2 10

the winner of competition #3 10

the winner of competition #4 10

the winner of competition #5 10

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int COLS = 5;
const int ROWS = 5;

int main()
{
    const int scores = 25;

    double competition[scores];

    cout << "Enter the scores of the 1st competition: ";
    cin >> competition[0];
    cin >> competition[1];
    cin >> competition[2];
    cin >> competition[3];
    cin >> competition[4];

    cout << "Enter the scores of the 2nd competition: ";
    cin >> competition[5];
    cin >> competition[6];
    cin >> competition[7];
    cin >> competition[8];
    cin >> competition[9];

    cout << "Enter the scores of the 3rd competition: ";
    cin >> competition[10];
    cin >> competition[11];
    cin >> competition[12];
    cin >> competition[13];
    cin >> competition[14];

    cout << "Enter the scores of the 4th competition: ";
    cin >> competition[15];
    cin >> competition[16];
    cin >> competition[17];
    cin >> competition[18];
    cin >> competition[19];

    cout << "Enter the scores of the 5th competition: ";
    cin >> competition[20];
    cin >> competition[21];
    cin >> competition[22];
    cin >> competition[23];
    cin >> competition[24];

 double table[ROWS][COLS] = {{competition[0], competition[1], competition[2], competition[3], competition[4]},
                             {competition[5], competition[6], competition[7], competition[8], competition[9]},
                             {competition[10], competition[11], competition[12], competition[13], competition[14]},
                             {competition[15], competition[16], competition[17], competition[18], competition[19]},
                             {competition[20], competition[21], competition[22], competition[23], competition[24]}};

    double max = competition[0];

for (int j = 0, k = 1; j < COLS; j++)
{
    cout << "the winner of competition #" << k++ << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        if (table[i][j] > max)
        {
            max = table[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << max << endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really you should just remove all the nonsense from your question and just explain what you're doing (trying to find the max value in groups of 5 in an array). You have your inputs and outputs which are good to know, but much of the rest of the text is irrelevant.

Comment: that looks like a code-review task, too much tautology that could be briefed in few lines.

Comment: Also there is a builtin [max](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/) function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset your max value after discovering one, preferably to 0 assuming that the lowest score possible to attain is 0. If you don't reset, your max will always compare with 10, and always return 10.

In general, while trying to find the max, you always initialize it to the minimum possible value of the data type it has. For example, for ints this is INT_MIN. You can find equivalent values for floats and doubles in [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Comment: Alternatively, reset the max to the first value in the subset of values being tested, like what is done for the first one. Ideally, `max` should just be initialised within subsetted values `for` loop, but it's not easy to see what's happening with `ROWS` and `COLS` which aren't declared. OP should probably use a 2d array to make this clearer.

Comment: I had a 2d array before but I was having trouble just set the max using it:      double max = table[0] and I would get the error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'double' with an lvalue of type 'double [5]'

Comment: @GinaCucchiara your table is bidimensional. you can't assign an array to int.

Comment: @Abra001 in my original post I did not include my table

Comment: @GinaCucchiara `double max = competition[0]` works because it is unidimensional, unlike `table` which is bidimensional.